# How to delete a row without affecting reference table using Elequent model in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I have two models called Parent and Child.

Parent model have:-

```
public function children(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Child');
}
```

Child model have:-

```
public function parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Parent');
}
```

parents table has the following data

```
id             name            data
1              ABC             ABCDEF
2              EFG             HIJKLM
```

children table has the following data

```
id             name            data                parent_id
1              123             123456                 1
2              456             789101112              1
```

I just want to delete the first row of children table using Eloquent models. It should not affect parent table.

I tried:-

```
$child=Child::find($id);
$child->delete();
```

and

```
$child=Child::find($id);
$child->parent()->delete();
$child->delete();
```

When I try both solutions which is mentioned above, It will delete row from both parent and child table. I want to delete a child table row with out deleting any row from parent table.
How can I achieve that?

migrations are:-
Parent migration is:-

```
Schema::create('parents', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->id();
     $table->string('name')->unique();
     $table->longText('data');
});
```

Child migration:-

```
Schema::create('children', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->id();
     $table->string('name');
     $table->longText('data');
     $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->index();
});

Schema::table('children', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('parents');
});
```

Comment: If you just want to delete a child row than it shouldn't be a problem, the first solution you posted should work. The second solution/example you posted would try to delete the parent row, is that what you want to do?

Comment: Share your migration

Comment: @RobertKujawa - I don't want to delete parent row. When I tried first solution, the parent row were deleted too.

Comment: @A.ANoman , I added migration to the question above, Thank you

Comment: remove the foreign key and it will work with you

Comment: This may sound strange, but what if Eloquent struggles with grammar? There are 2 grammatical mistakes. The plural of 'child' is 'children'. If you look into the Str::plural() helper, you'll find that 'child' => 'children' is listed there. The other is that children have one parent, not parents. You can define ORM custom models to overcome this without changing your database. As explained in https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships Grammar does matter if you follow the default Laravel ORM conventions.